# How to subscribe to error case in angular service unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, angular2-services, angular-test

I am trying to subscribe to the response and as well the error case but when I see the coverage its not going to err case.

I have the following fake service,

My service,

```
fakeService: {

     appVersion() : {

        return of({'version':'1.2.3.4'})
     } 
}
```

test case1:

```
 it('Should load version',() => {

    fakeService.appVersion().subscribe((data) {

      expect(data.version).toBe(1.2.3.4)

  });
```

test case 2: [for error case]

```
  it('Should return error',() => {
   fakeService: {

     appVersion() : {

        return throwError('Error');
     } 
   }
    fakeService.appVersion().subscribe({
     error : err => expect(err).toBe('Error');

  });
 }
```

In component

```
   myService.appVersion.subscribe((data) {
      if (data) {
       //// Covered
      } else (err) {
       //// Not covered
      }

   });
```

I am trying to subscribe to the response and as well the error case but when I see the coverage its not going to err case.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're not really testing the error case for that subscribe. To do that you would need something more like

```
myService.appVersion().subscribe((data) {
  if (data) {
    //// Covered
  }
}, (err) => {
    //// Now covered
  }
});
```

With the way you've written it you would be able to test it by using

```
fakeService: {
  appVersion() : {
    return of(null);
  } 
}
```